# What happens to ECDSA public key if a constant is added to private key?

Tags: private-key, public-key, ecdsa

Consider I have a random number on curve Secp256k1 as the private key. I know if I calculate G multiplied by the private key in EC domain, I get the public key.

I am wondering what happens to public key if I add a constant value to the private key? How can one calculate the resulting key?

In addition, it would be great if someone leads me to a proper reference to learn the mathematic behind Elliptic Curves.